# [PHP]SQL table giving incorrect values from session variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I store my user permissions in the same table as the user information, such that there are three boolean entries, for the three permission levels. Upon login, the data from that user's row is inserted into session variables with the following code:

```
private function loginWithPostData($user_name, $user_password, $user_rememberme)
{
    if (empty($user_name)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_EMPTY;
    } else if (empty($user_password)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_EMPTY;

    // if POST data (from login form) contains non-empty user_name and non-empty user_password
    } else {
        // user can login with his username or his email address.
        // if user has not typed a valid email address, we try to identify him with his user_name
        if (!filter_var($user_name, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // database query, getting all the info of the selected user
            $result_row = $this->getUserData(trim($user_name));

        // if user has typed a valid email address, we try to identify him with his user_email
        } else if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
            // database query, getting all the info of the selected user
            $query_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = :user_email');
            $query_user->bindValue(':user_email', trim($user_name), PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_user->execute();
            // get result row (as an object)
            $result_row = $query_user->fetchObject();
        }

        // if this user not exists
        if (! isset($result_row->user_id)) {
            // was MESSAGE_USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST before, but has changed to MESSAGE_LOGIN_FAILED
            // to prevent potential attackers showing if the user exists
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_LOGIN_FAILED;
        } else if (($result_row->user_failed_logins >= 3) && ($result_row->user_last_failed_login > (time() - 30))) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_WRONG_3_TIMES;
        // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided passwords fits to the hash of that user's password
        } else if (! password_verify($user_password, $result_row->user_password_hash)) {
            // increment the failed login counter for that user
            $sth = $this->db_connection->prepare('UPDATE users '
                    . 'SET user_failed_logins = user_failed_logins+1, user_last_failed_login = :user_last_failed_login '
                    . 'WHERE user_name = :user_name OR user_email = :user_name');
            $sth->execute(array(':user_name' => $user_name, ':user_last_failed_login' => time()));

            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_WRONG;
        // has the user activated their account with the verification email
        } else if ($result_row->user_active != 1) {
            $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_ACCOUNT_NOT_ACTIVATED;
        } else {
            // write user data into PHP SESSION [a file on your server]
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result_row->user_id;
            $_SESSION['user_name'] = $result_row->user_name;
            $_SESSION['user_email'] = $result_row->user_email;
            $_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['user_first_name'] = $result_row->user_first_name;
            $_SESSION['user_last_name'] = $result_row->user_last_name;
            $_SESSION['user_address_line_1'] = $result_row->user_address_line_1;
            $_SESSION['permission_1'] = $result_row->permission_1;
            $_SESSION['permission_2'] = $result_row->permission_2;
            $_SESSION['permission_3'] = $result_row->permission_3;

            // declare user id, set the login status to true
            $this->user_id = $result_row->user_id;
            $this->user_name = $result_row->user_name;
            $this->user_email = $result_row->user_email;
            $this->user_is_logged_in = true;
```

Now when I use PHP to tell me which of the columns has a 1, I get incorrect data, though using the same method for all the other data (first name, email address etc.) works perfectly.This is the code I use for that:

```
    if($_SESSION['permission_1'] = 1){
    echo "ADMIN";
} else {
    if($_SESSION['permission_2'] = 1){
        echo "MANAGEMENT COMPANY";
    } else {
        if($_SESSION['permission_3'] = 1){
            echo "USER";
        } else {
            echo "You do not currently have any permissions. Please wait for a member of the management team to verify you.";
        }
    }
}
```

What have I done to cause only boolean values to either not be destroyed at the end of a session or to report inaccurately?

Comment: Looks like you are setting permission_admin, permission_lessor etc and not permission_1, permission_2 ?

Comment: Yeah, I was changing those here, they are all perm_admin, lessor etc in the code, I thought id changed them all, its not that..

Comment: Can you update the code and also what does var_dump($_SESSION) show?

Comment: Explain me what does this code do `if($_SESSION['permission_1'] = 1)`?  Is it a condition or an assignment? It's wrong!

Comment: @traianTatic I'm trying to output text, so if permission_1 = 1, then it'll say you have admin permissions, if not, check for permission_2, call it Management Company etc.. what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a `=` try changing it in all of the `if()`s like this:

```
$_SESSION['permission_3'] == 1
```

in PHP `=` assigns a value,`==` checks it (also `===` checks if the type is the same in the comparison)

Comment: Also, there's no need to use 3 variables/ rows for setting the permissions. Use one variable/ row that can take 3 values, for example A, M and U. Same result, less lines, less trouble.